# backward nslookup ip in DNS setup centos 8

Tags: dns, nslookup, dig, reverse-dns

I setup a DNS server on CentOS 8.
But the command "nslookup " has not correct output. The output not contains the nameservers which I set for it.

Comment: *"But the command "nslookup " has not correct output."* - While I have added a general answer regarding some things which might relate to your issue, you may wish [edit] your question to show the exact command you are using, the output you receive and the output you expect.

Answer (score 0):

**General Thoughts**

- I have noticed that the `Serial` for your zone(s) has remained at `3` over several posts. The `Serial` entry for a given zone needs to be incremented each time changes are made to that zone file. Failing to update this `Serial` for each set of changes could result in new changes being ignored.
- Assuming that you are using ex. `nslookup -type=ns sudia.com`, you may need to add the name or IP address of your name server in order to query the correct records e.g.:

  ```
   nslookup -type=ns sudia.com your.name.server

   nslookup -type=ns sudia.com 1.2.3.4
  ```
- These can be local or remote names/IPs but be aware different values may return different results.
- You may wish to double-check that your domain is correctly set up to use your name servers (ex. via your registrar's domain control panel). This may include subdomain entries for e.g. `ns1.sudia.com` and `ns2.sudia.com` as well as glue records.
- Reverse zones are effectively optional and should not affect what name servers are returned.

**Other Notes**

While it shouldn't have anything to do with your issue, you are missing a period on your final reverse pointer entry domain (this could be a simple cut and paste error).

Also, as a small note on the SOA record in your example, I don't believe `ns2.sudia.com.` is doing what I presume you might think it does. Assuming that you wish to [add two name servers in a DNS forward file](https://superuser.com/questions/1563004/how-to-add-two-name-servers-in-dns-forward-file/1563063#1563063), only e.g. `ns1.sudia.com.` is required, even when two or more name server entries exist for the zone.

In an SOA record, the "second" entry before the `()` is an email address. So, in your example:

```
@   IN  SOA     ns1.sudia.com. ns2.sudia.com. (
```

the entry `ns1.sudia.com.` specifies a nameserver and `ns2.sudia.com.` specifies an email address (`ns@sudia.com`) for contacting e.g. the domain owner. In the long rung, it doesn't matter what you have for the second entry ex.:

```
@   IN  SOA     ns1.sudia.com. totally-fake-email.example.com. (
```

But while the second "email" entry is required broadly, to reiterate, having the name of your second name server there serves no purpose.

*ex. var/named/fwd.sudia.com.db* (with SOA email reminder)

```
@   IN  SOA     ns1.sudia.com. email.sudia.com. (
                                               6           ;Serial
                                               3600        ;Refresh
                                               1800        ;Retry
                                               604800      ;Expire
                                               86400       ;Minimum TTL
)

;Name Server Information
@       IN  NS      ns1.sudia.com.
@       IN  NS      ns2.sudia.com.

;IP address of Name Server
ns1       IN  A       136.243.197.164
ns2       IN  A       136.243.197.164

;A - Record Host Name To IP Address
sudia.com.     IN  A       136.243.197.164
www             IN  A       136.243.197.164

;CNAME record
ftp     IN CNAME        www.sudia.com.
```

*Reverse DNS Zone* (with SOA email reminder)

```
@   IN  SOA     ns1.sudia.com. email.sudia.com. (
                                               6           ;Serial
                                               3600        ;Refresh
                                               1800        ;Retry
                                               604800      ;Expire
                                               86400       ;Minimum TTL
)

;Name Server Information
@         IN NS         ns1.sudia.com.
@         IN NS         ns2.sudia.com.

;Reverse lookup for Name Server 164
164        IN  PTR     ns1.sudia.com.
164        IN  PTR     ns2.sudia.com.

;PTR Record IP address to Host Name
164      IN  PTR     www.sudia.com.
```